# trying to install sqlite3 on debian 11

Tags: python, sqlite, debian

```
  File "/root/bot/venvBot/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tortoise/backends/sqlite/client.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

I tried to install `sqlite-devel` and `libsqlite3-dev` but they did not help and if I try to install pysqlite I get an error and `pysqlite3` is already installed

When I try to install sqlite3 itself, it comes out like this

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sqlite3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sqlite3
```

Error when using sqlite3

Comment: Did you install sqlite3? `sudo apt install sqlite3`

Comment: sqlite3 is already the newest version (3.34.1-3).

Comment: it still doesn't help

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: i use virtual environment

Comment: But sqlite python bindings do not seem to be installed into venv as the path shows exactly that it is being loaded off from `/usr/local/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/`

Comment: and what should I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be that python exists before you install sqlite3. Before installing python, you need to ensure that the sqlite3 library is installed and can be found, so there are two ways:

1. Uninstall and reinstall python.
2. Create a new virtual environmentand use it.